# Indy : Object[i].delete method can't free memory?

Tags: delphi, indy10

This is my simple code for queue[i] freeing memory ...
Is it correct?

The monitor is a customized TIdContext object.

```
   ...
   var queue : TList;
   ...

    queue := monitor.Screenshots.LockList;
    if queue.Count > 0 then
    begin
      for i := 0 to queue.Count - 1 do
      begin
        if TScreenshotInfo(queue[i]).ClientIP = request_AgentIP then
        begin
          screenshot := TScreenshotInfo(queue[i]);
        end;
        queue.Delete(i);//Can't free queue[i] from memory?
      end;
    end;
...
```

Comment: Assuming from your previous post that `queue = TList`, use `TObjectlist` instead which will automatically free the object for you...

Comment: You mean queue[i].delete can free memory, if I use TObjectList instead of TList?

Comment: yes indeed, that's what I mean

Comment: You should learn the difference between freeing an object and removing a queue entry. They're hardly the same, any more than removing an apple from the tree magically makes the apple disappear from the planet.

Answer (score 1):

```
queue := monitor.Screenshots.LockList;
try
  for queue.Count-1 downto 0 do begin
    if TScreenshotInfo(queue[i]).ClientIP = request_AgentIP then
      TScreenshotInfo(queue[i]).Free;//queue[i] freed
    queue.Delete(i);
  end;
finally
  monitor.Screenshots.UnlockList;
end;
```

I assume there's some reason why an item is deleted and not freed if it doesn't match the condition.

Comment: Oh, Sorry but, the queue at the condition of equaling with request_AgentIP should not be free.. and others must be free all.

Comment: Thanks. understood... Then you mean queue[i].free only can free memory, Is is correct ?

Comment: Using `TList` a call to `Free` is needed. Using `TObjectList` the delete operation frees the underlying object for you, like the [@whosrdaddy's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33911939/indy-objecti-delete-method-cant-free-memory#comment55586351_33911939) pointed out

Answer (score 0):

As I already explained in comments to [your other question on this same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33903537/):

> You have memory leaks in `IdTCPServer_SendExecute()`. `IdTCPServer_RecvExecute()` queues a screenshot to all connected monitors, but `IdTCPServer_SendExecute()` only processes screenshots from a specific client, discarding all other client screenshots from the queue without freeing them from memory. Also, if multiple screenshots from the desired client are in the queue, you only process the last screenshot, discarding the earlier screenshots without freeing them. In short, your loop processing in `IdTCPServer_SendExecute()` has logic holes in it.

The code needs to look more like this:

```
destructor TMonitorContext.Destroy;
var
  queue: TList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  queue := Screenshots.LockList;
  try
    for i := 0 to queue.Count - 1 do begin
      TScreenshotInfo(queue[i]).Free;
    end;
  finally
    Screenshots.UnlockList;
  end;
  Screenshots.Free;
  CloseHandle(ScreenshotEvent);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TIndyServerForm.IdTCPServer_SendExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  monitor: TMonitorContext;
  queue: TList;
  screenshot: TScreenshotInfo;
  request_AgentIP: string;
begin
  monitor := TMonitorContext(AContext);

  if WaitForSingleObject(monitor.ScreenshotEvent, 1000) <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 then begin
    Exit;
  end;

  // you really should not be requesting an IP on every screenshot sent.
  // request an IP once at connection, and don't request a new IP unless
  // you want to monitor a different client.  This is especially useful
  // for allowing IdTCPServer_Recv to not queue screenshots this monitor
  // is not interested in receiving...
  request_AgentIP := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;

  screenshot := nil;
  try
    queue := monitor.Screenshots.LockList;
    try
      while queue.Count > 0 do
      begin
        screenshot := TScreenshotInfo(queue[0]);
        queue.Delete(0);
        if screenshot.ClientIP = request_AgentIP then
          Break;
        end;
        FreeAndNil(screenshot);
      end;
      if queue.Count = 0 then
        ResetEvent(monitor.ScreenshotEvent);
    finally
      monitor.Screenshots.UnlockList;
    end;
    if screenshot = nil then begin
      Exit;
    end;
    // you should send screenshot.ClientIP and screenshot.ClientPort to
    // this monitor so it knows which client the screenshot came from...
    if not SendStream(AContext, screenshot.Data) then
    begin
      SOutMsg :='viewer : ' + AContext.Binding.PeerIP + ': reqIP(' + request_AgentIP + ')-> image send failed : ' + KBStr(screenshot.Data.Size) +' @'+TimeToStr(Now);
      AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
    end
    else
    begin
      SOutMsg :='viewer : ' + AContext.Binding.PeerIP + ': reqIP(' + request_AgentIP + ')->  image send success : ' + KBStr(screenshot.Data.Size)+' @'+TimeToStr(Now);
    end;
  finally
    screenshot.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank your advice....  I will try with your code again. And I couldn't vote your answers and comments because of downgrading my accounts. really sorry.